# Как вывести все поля из связанных моделей в GridView

Tags: yii2

У меня есть несколько таблиц с отношениями (через одну и через две), и отношения эти работают.
К примеру, в модели Player есть

```
     public function getPts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Pt::className(), ['player_id' => 'id']);
    } 

   public function getTournaments()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Tournament::className(),
           ['id' => 'tournament_id'])->via('teams');
   }
```

Когда я пишу в контроллере PlayerController

```
 public function actionIndex()
    {
        $query = Player::findOne(3077)->getPts();
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);

    }
```

я получаю в Gridview доступ к полям из таблицы pt, 
если меняю `getPts()`на `getTournaments()` то могу вывести поля из tournament.

А как сделать чтобы получить все поля, из обеих таблиц? Подскажите, перечитал все руководства уже - застрял и всё.

Comment: а зачем использовать провайдер для того, чтобы вытащить один объект данных?

Comment: а как без него? Подскажите, я еще только начинающий)

Answer (score 1):

Во первых вам нужно уточнить свой вопрос, что имеется ввиду к полям из таблицы , у вас связь hasMany, вы хотите получить к полям рельтата запроса? или все же просто к единым полям

В Yii2 связи подхватываются автоматически, на то он и магический метод геттер.
В Grid view вам необходимо получать доступ к полям из связей так: пример

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'username',
        'tournaments.id',
        'pts.(название поля из связи)',
        'названиесвязи  . название поля'
    ],
]);
```

при наличии связи hasMany , необходимо обрабатывать список результатов к примеру через анонимную функцию

```
 [
'attribute' => 'test.pp',
            'value' => function ($data) {
             $res = null;          
           foreach($data->*** as $resault) {
              $res .= '<p>'.$resault->name .'</p>;
            }
           return $res;
            },
        ],
```

надо только посмотреть где в $data хранится массив с результатами

Comment: К полям результата запроса, которые я указываю в GridView. Так как у меня сейчас есть - то есть если в контроллере `$query = Player::findOne(3077)->getPts();` я могу получить поля из таблицы pt указав их напрямую (team_id)

Comment: не понял, подробнее пожалуйста

Comment: Если я делаю в контроллере `$query = Player::find();` тогда я указываю поля так, как вы сказали, т. е. `'pts.(название поля из связи)'` - но в этом случае они выводятся пустыми. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: То есть я не могу сделать так, чтобы в одной таблице GridView у меня были поля player.id, player.name, pt.team_id, tournament.name. Только из какой-то одной таблицы, а как сделать чтобы они все были выведены?

Comment: Потому что у вас связь hasmany, когда вы делается ->getPts(); и выводите, то получаете первую строку( а их там может больше )

Comment: Когда я делаю ->getPts() я получаю ровно столько строк, сколько у меня в таблице pt. То есть на одного id из таблицы player выводится несколько связанных id из pt (на одного игрока несколько команд, в которых он выступал - таблица pt это отношение player-teams). То есть я получаю эти id команд в таблице (пусть их будет два), но не могу в той же таблице вывести id игрока (и его имя тоже). А мне это именно и нужно. Простите, что вопрос запутанный - но простые я стараюсь решать сам, сюда пишу просто потому что у меня никак не хватает сообразить что же нужно поменять

Comment: я дополнил ответ, но не уверен , что это то , что вам нужно. т.к я до конца не могу понять ваше изложение проблемы

Comment: Спасибо за готовность помочь! Я сделал по другому: за основу взял модель pt, у которой со всеми отношения hasOne. А там уже проблем нет, можно просто добавлять в гридвью поля в виде таблица.поле и всё работает. Двое суток мучался)) С HasMany так и не разобрался - возможно есть какой-то способ, конечно.